# Setting a condition based redirect in a class based view (Django)

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm (beginner) creating a simple blog app. I created a class based view to create a blog post and it has a separate URL. I want it redirect to the login page (url name = 'login') if the user isn't logged in. In a function based view all I have to do is this:

```
def postCreateView(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('login')
```

I don't know how to do this in a class based view (inherited from generic CreateView). I tried modifying the **init**() method like this:

```
def redirectLogin(self):
     return redirect('login')

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if(not self.request.user.is_authenticated):
         redirectLogin()
     super().__init__()
```

(I named the class PostCreateView) But on debugging the Exception Value was `'PostCreateView' object has no attribute 'request'`. I need the correct way (The Django convention way if it exists) to set a condition based redirect in class based view.

Also I'm confused why it says the view doesn't have an attribute 'request'. Every view has request. I'm sure about it because I overrode the `form_valid()` method to set the author of the post as the currently logged in user like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid()
```

And it run perfectly fine when I logged in and created a post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every view has request. I'm sure about it because I overrode the `form_valid()`

**No,** since that is the constructor. You immediately make the check when you construct a view object, and at that time, the `request`, `args` and `kwargs` are *not* yet set. In fact these are set just after the object is constructed. You can see this in the source code of the [**`view`** function [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L61:L76):

> ```
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
>                 self.head = self.get
>             self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>             if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
>                 raise AttributeError(
>                     "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
>                     "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
>                 )
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

and the [**`setup`** function [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L83:L87) sets the `.request`, `.args` and `.kwargs`:

> ```
>     def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         """Initialize attributes shared by all view methods."""
>         self.request = request
>         self.args = args
>         self.kwargs = kwargs
> ```

Even if there was a request object however, that would not fix the problem, since returning a `redirect` in the `__init__` is not something the underlying view mechanism will anticipate on, and it will thus, likely, somewhere raise another error.

That being said, what you here do is already done before. You can use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is already built-in Django, so no need to re-invent the wheel here: [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) and [LoginRequired Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)

Your approach is wrong because you're overriding `__init__`; if you want to do your checks before *executing* a view, you might wanna look into overriding `dispatch()`

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return redirect()
```